# Loadrunner 12.60: controller failed to save load test scenarios

Tags: controller, loadrunner

Loadrunner 12.60, the environment is windows 10 Home version.

open controller, choose the right loadrunner script for test.
choose the run mode, click save. Error message prompted.
Loadrunner controller has encountered a problem and needs to close. the exception details are as per below:

Wlrun.exe caused an Microsoft C++ Exception in module KERNELBASE.dll at 0023:747418A2, RaiseException()+0098 byte(s)

Tried to run controller with 'run as Administration' and the same issue ocurred.

Answer (score 0):

Run it on a professional edition of Windows or higher

Comment: thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, my two laptops at home are Windows10 Home. pls advise if Loadrunner 12.60 support the home 64 bit OS. Regards

Comment: I have never known, in 20+ years of experience with LoadRunner across MicroFocus, HP or Mercury, for the home edition of Windows to be a supported platform.   It could well be in the latest release as I haven't read the system requirements documentation which is installed with your release, but I would never run it as such.  May I recommend a virtual machine on AWS EC2

Comment: confirmed only the windows10 pro is the right platform for LR12.62. Regards

Answer (score 0):

From this [URL](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60-12.62/help/PDFs/PC_LR_System_Requirements_12.60.pdf)，you could find the LoadRunner 12.60 Requirments.

From this document, you will find LR only support Win 10 64-bit.
So you could check your Win 10 version first.
[image: LoadRunner Requirement]

Comment: thank you for responding my question. Just checked my PC, my windows is 64 bit. refer the below snapshot for further information. Please advise why it is not working as expected.

Comment: Have you updated Win10 Home to 2018 Fall (October) update? Please try it. If LR Requirement list supported to Win 10 64-bit, I think LR should also support Windows 10 64-bit Home edition.

Comment: Besides, I suggest you could update LR 12.60 to 12.62.

Comment: installed the LR12.60 at windows10 Pro and everything works as expected. Don't think win10 Home is the right platform for LR 12.62. Thank you for sharing it